# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting an error in Jupyter notebook:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer= SimpleImputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis= 0)
```

and my error is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-9f8271dfdf3c> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
----> 2 imputer= SimpleImputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis= 0)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html), `SimpleImputer` does not accept an `axis` arg. Please specify what exactly are you trying to achieve. What is the problem statement?

Comment: @amanb thanks, i want to take care of  missing values by replacing

Comment: The docs cover this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.NAN, strategy= 'mean', fill_value=None, verbose=0, copy=True)
```

Comment: Why is this better? What is wrong with the original way of doing it?

Answer (score 4):

In `SimpleImputer` the axis parameter has been removed. In the deprecated `Imputer` class, it was used to specify whether values should be imputed along columns (`axis=0`, the default), or along rows (`axis=1`). Apparently, this differentiation is no longer supported in the new `SimpleImputer` class. There is some information about this here:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10636

If you are imputing along columns (which it appears the original poster is), then just drop the axis parameter and you should get the same behavior. If you need to impute along rows, then I don't know what other options are available. I could not find an answer to this with some searching.